# Swift Casting Generic to Optional with a nil value causes fatalError

Tags: swift, generics, swift2

Using Swift 2, in my contrived example I am converting a `String` to an `Int` or more specifically an `Int` or an `Int?` using a generic. In the case where the `Int?` should be nil the cast will fail with a fatalError: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

These look like they may be similar/duplicate questions:

- [Swift - casting a nil core data string as an optional value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27411837/swift-casting-a-nil-core-data-string-as-an-optional-value)
- [Swift: detecting an unexpected nil value in a non-optional at runtime: casting as optional fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29031080/swift-detecting-an-unexpected-nil-value-in-a-non-optional-at-runtime-casting-a)

**My question is: how is one supposed to cast to an optional that is nil?**

Example:

```
class Thing<T>{
    var item: T

    init(_ item: T){
        self.item = item
    }
}

struct Actions{

    static func convertIntForThing<T>(string: String, thing:Thing<T>) -> T{
        return convertStringToInt(string, to: T.self)
    }

    static func convertStringToInt<T>(string: String, to: T.Type) -> T{
        debugPrint("Converting to ---> \(to)")

        if T.self == Int.self{
            return Int(string)! as! T
        }

        // in the case of "" Int? will be nil, the cast
        // here causes it to blow up with:
        //
        // fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
        // Optional value even though T in this case is an Optional<Int>
        return Int(string) as! T

    }
}


func testExample() {
    // this WORKS:
    let thing1 = Thing<Int>(0)
    thing1.item = Actions.convertIntForThing("1", thing: thing1)

    // This FAILS:
    // empty string  where value = Int("")
    // will return an Optional<Int> that will be nil
    let thing2 = Thing<Int?>(0)
    thing2.item = Actions.convertIntForThing("", thing: thing2)
}

testExample()
```

Comment: "how is one supposed to cast to an optional that is nil" You can't. The question makes no sense. There is no there there - there's nothing to cast. It is nil. You can _test_ it but you can't _cast_ it.

Comment: It can be changed to return `nil` but then the compiler complains that nil is incompatible with return type `T`.  In the case where `T` is `Int?` though, `nil` would be a valid value.

Comment: You have to _make_ the correct kind of nil. Try returning `Optional<T>.None`.

Comment: But I grant that this may not work for a generic. I've seen lots of issues where the generic placeholder type is supposed to be an Optional. It just doesn't work.

Comment: ya, even if I do this: `return Optional<Int>.None as! T` it blows up... I'm thinking your last comment is probably spot on. Optional Generics are problematic.  Same fatalError, `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: Yeah, I think if you do a search you will find a _lot_ of questions about generics where the placeholder is supposed to be resolved to an Optional. The problem is that there is not _inherent_ relationship between an Optional and the thing it wraps; the Optional is a _different type_, a type that is _itself_ a generic.

Comment: I got something that does work. I forgot that Optional is a `NilLiteralConvertible`. So when I do this https://gist.github.com/aventurella/dd67b6394c87d5551e74 it doesn't fail. Basically provides a constraint on `T where T: NilLiteralConvertible`

Comment: Cool-o-rama! Answer your own question so I can up vote your answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can't *cast* nil to some-kind-of-nil, but you can *make* some-kind-of-nil, as this artificial example shows:

```
    func test(s:String) -> Int? {
        var which : Bool { return Int(s) != nil }
        if which {
            return (Int(s)! as Int?)
        } else {
            return (Optional<Int>.None)
        }
    }

    print(test("12"))
    print(test("howdy"))
```

Answer (score 2):

I got something that does work.

I forgot that `Optional` is a `NilLiteralConvertible`. So we can provide 2 variations on the conversion function and it will not fail. Basically, provides a constraint on `T` where `T: NilLiteralConvertible`

```
class Thing<T>{
    var item: T

    init(_ item: T){
        self.item = item
    }
}

struct Actions{

    // Provide 2 variations one with T the other where T: NilLiteralConvertible
    // variation 1 for non-optionals
    static func convertIntForThing<T>(string: String, thing:Thing<T>) -> T{
        return convertStringToInt(string, to: T.self)
    }

    // variation 2 for optionals
    static func convertIntForThing<T where T: NilLiteralConvertible>(string: String, thing:Thing<T>) -> T{
        return convertStringToInt(string, to: T.self)
    }

    static func convertStringToInt<T>(string: String, to: T.Type) -> T{
        debugPrint("Converting to ---> \(to)")
        return Int(string)! as! T
    }

    static func convertStringToInt<T where T: NilLiteralConvertible>(string: String, to: T.Type) -> T{
        debugPrint("Converting to ---> \(to)")

        let value = Int(string)

        if let _ = value{
            return value as! T
        }

        let other: T = nil
        return other
    }
}

func testExample() {
    // this WORKS:
    let thing1 = Thing<Int>(0)
    thing1.item = Actions.convertIntForThing("1", thing: thing1)

    let thing2 = Thing<Int?>(0)
    thing2.item = Actions.convertIntForThing("", thing: thing2)
}

testExample()
```

Comment: In 48 hours you can accept your own answer, and you should do so. This is totally normal and correct Stack Overflow behavior, and helps others.

Answer (score 0):

Generally casting in Swift has sometimes weird behaviors when you are working with generic types. A simple workaround would be to make a generic casting function:

```
func cast<T, U>(value: T, type: U.Type) -> U {
    return value as! U
}
```

Now you can rewrite the casting to:

```
return cast(Int(string), type: T.self)
```

Comment: That also worked. In the case of the `Int?` I had to do this with that casting function: `let value = cast(Int(""), type: (Int?.self)!)`  as T.self is an unresolved identifier in that context.  This also does the trick with less ?!: `let value = cast(Int(""), type: Optional<Int>.self)`

Comment: @AdamVenturella Try `(Int?).self` instead since the compiler thinks that the `?` is in this case optional chaining rather than a type.

Comment: You learn something new everyday. I was wondering why it was so awkward to get the type of an optional. I could tell that the compiler thought it needed to be unwrapped, did not even consider `(Int?).self` Thanks for that!