# Swift: Nil is incompatible with return type String

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, guard

I have this code in Swift:

```
guard let user = username else{
        return nil
    }
```

But I'm getting the following errors:

```
Nil is incompatible with return type String
```

Any of you knows why or how I return nil in this case?

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: you can't return the Nil value in swift, change your return type String in your method

Comment: this may help you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32232392/swift-casting-generic-to-optional-with-a-nil-value-causes-fatalerror

Comment: show more code of your function, namely its return type.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik you can return nil in swift when the return type is optional (the Optional type implements NilLiteralConvertible). 
The issue is that the return type of the method is String. If he wants the ability to return nil then the return type should be String?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to tell the compiler that you want to return `nil`. How do you that? By assigning `?` after your object. For instance, take a look at this code:

```
func newFriend(friendDictionary: [String : String]) -> Friend? {
    guard let name = friendDictionary["name"], let age = friendDictionary["age"] else {
        return nil
    }
    let address = friendDictionary["address"]
    return Friend(name: name, age: age, address: address)
}
```

Notice how I needed to tell the compiler that my object `Friend`, which I'm returning, is an **optional** `Friend?`. Otherwise it will throw an error.

Comment: Very nice answer.

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 28):

Does your function declare an optional return type?

func foo() -> String? { ...

See more on: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html

> NOTE
>
> The concept of optionals doesn’t exist in C or Objective-C. The
>   nearest thing in Objective-C is the ability to return nil from a
>   method that would otherwise return an object, with nil meaning “the
>   absence of a valid object.”

Answer (score 0):

**Does your function declare an optional return type?*

```
func minAndmax(array:[Int])->(min:Int, max:Int)? {
    if array.isEmpty {
        return nil
    }

    var currentMin = array[0]
    var currentMax = array[0]

    for value in array {
        if value < currentMin {
            currentMin = value
        }
        else if value > currentMax {
            currentMax = value
        }
    
    }
    return (currentMin, currentMax)
}

if let bounds = minAndmax(array:  [8, -6, 2, 109, 3, 71]) {
    print(bounds)
}
```