# SwiftUI NSData comparing non-optional value which is actually optional

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, core-data, swiftui

I am using CoreData in SwiftUI for MacOS. I am using `Binary Data` inside an entity in CoreData to store my images.

Everything is working fine.. this attribute should be optional and it is marked as `optional`.
When I wanna use that Data, I always check first if it is `not nil` and then use it.

If it is `nil` I want to display a default image. That is working totally fine.

Nevertheless, SwiftUI always gives me an error message when comparing that value with `nil`.

Image is my BinaryData attribute at person.

**This line:**

```
if (person.image != nil)
```

... causes that error message.

> Comparing non-optional value of type 'NSData' to 'nil' always returns
>   true

I understand the message, but I want it to have it as optional. And the comparison it still working, even though it should always return true.

[image]

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33548350/3985749).

Comment: @pbasdf Thank you sir.. didn't find it though. Was able to solve

Comment: So my model class and the attribute inspector in database are not getting synced right? When I am using custom model